# Deserializing complex JSON using C#

Tags: c#, json

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public EnPickthall enpickthall { get; set; }
}

public class EnPickthall
{
    public _1 _1 { get; set; }
    public _2 _2 { get; set; }
    public _3 _3 { get; set; }
    public _4 _4 { get; set; }
    /* This goes on*/
    public _6236 _6236 { get; set;}
}

 //For Each of the above properties a separate class has been defined:
public class _1
{
public int id { get; set; }
public int surah { get; set; }
public int ayah { get; set; }
public string verse { get; set; }
}

public class _2
{
public int id { get; set; }
public int surah { get; set; }
public int ayah { get; set; }
public string verse { get; set; }
}
/* So On for all the properties */
```

I got this via JSON2CSHARP!
My problem is if I employ so many properties retrieving all Verses based upon their "Surah" would be very  ***difficult & Impractical***

Here I have a book in EnPickthall class which has a separate Class for every verse. Every Verse here has it's own class.

I have been scavenging Stack Overflow for hours.Is there any way I could simplify this JSON Classes.

My Code to Creating the object model :

```
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject_Quran));
        var result= App_Code.FileIOHelper.ReadFromDefaultFile("ms-appx:///Assets/en.pickthall.json");

        var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));

        var data = (RootObject_Quran)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

My JSON File Link : http://globalquran.com/download/data/download.php?data_by=json&quran_by_id[]=en.pickthall

Comment: There are alot of ways to simplify, but what exactly are you trying to achieve? Could you explain your code a bit? What are the properties : public _1 _1 { get; set; } for ? Do they need to be attributes with their own classes ? Would not a type of list suffice? A Dictionary, hash-table, or just a regular List<t> ?

Comment: @Nobody  Actually this is a religious book stored in JSON format on my HDD.I directly generated Classes for It using JSON2Csharp where every verse is stored as a seperate property in the class EnPickthall . And every verse has it's own id, Surah(chapter),Aya(Verse Number) & Verse(Content of Verse)

Comment: Why not have `public class EnPickthall { public List<Verse> Verses { get; set; }` and `public class Verse { public int id { get; set; } ... }`?

Comment: It looks to me like you only really need one class, Verse, which has SurahId (Integer), AyaId (Integer) and Content (String) properties. Then, you can easily gather those verses into the entire Quran by ordering them on SurahId and AyaId accordingly. Or you could invert it and have a Quran contain a list of Surahs, each containing a List of Ayas, which contain text. But that seems like unnecessary embedding of Lists to me. I'd do this bottom up, rather than top down. With this constant object definition, it would be easily serialized/deserialized.

Comment: That is what I was thinking also. Just make an generic Verse class, then on EnPickthall, have a List of all verse objects. There isn't much reason to have each verse have it's own class object. When they don't differ in any way. You can always fetch the correct object from the list using it's ID, Surah, or any other property.

Comment: @Bardicer the problem I am having with that approach is that even though I am getting the correct Json response, the Enpickthall type property is always null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json is nested with property en.pickthall than all data wrapper again into property like id numbers so i made class and that class has Dictionary to handle data and numbers
**[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "en.pickthall")] 

public Dictionary picthall {get;set;}**

```
    public class VerseObject
    {

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "en.pickthall")]
        public Dictionary<int, Data> picthall {get;set;}


    }
    public class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public int id;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "surah")]
        public int surah;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ayah")]
        public int ayah;
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "verse")]
        public string verse;

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Data> v = new List<Data>();
            using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\en.pickthall.json"))
            {
                var str = rdr.ReadToEnd();
                var jsn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VerseObject>(str);
                foreach(var item in jsn.picthall.Select(x=>x.Value))
                {
                    v.Add(item);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just have a single class called Verse.

```
public class Verse {
    public int SurahId { get; set; }

    public int AyaId { get; set; }

    public String Text { get; set; }
}
```

You don't really need a key for each verse, as the surah/aya combination is sufficient to uniquely identify a verse.

This allows for easy serialization/deserialization and also allows for easy gathering into the entire Quran again, by ordering on Surah and Aya. You could then simply use LINQ to reassemble the entire book, ordered as state above. Or it would be incredibly simple to gather passages from it also, based on a search criteria e.g. 27:18-20

Comment: the problem I am having with that approach is that even though I am getting the correct Json response, the Enpickthall type property is always null

Comment: You will have to do a bit of manual serialization/deserialization. You'd need to do something like this:
 deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Verse>(JsonStringOftheVerseObjects);

Take a look at: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: It's simply an array of verse objects. The verse can contain its parent Surah/Aya combo as key. Simple. No need for anything else as they can be derived easily from the verses themselves using LINQ :)

Comment: @ManoDestra thanks for the effort. I tried http://pastebin.com/F5Bfx5zx. Still didn't work. Error : The data contract type 'App_Code.Verse' cannot be deserialized because the required data members 'ayah, id, surah, verse' were not found. I am using the file from "globalquran.com/download/data"

Comment: Ah. I see. Would have been useful to know that you were trying to deserialize FIRST, rather than serialize, then deserialize. I'll take a look at it again.

Comment: Can you post an example of the JSON format returned by that API in your question?

Comment: @ManoDestra here is the link to my JSON file I am using : (http://globalquran.com/download/data/download.php?data_by=json&quran_by_id[]=en.pickthall) it's worth 1 mb

Comment: Thanks for that. I see how they've done it now. There's some redundancy in their JSON format. The surah Id's outside of the verses are not required, as each verse already stores that info within it anyway. I'd ignore the external attributes and simply read in the lower level verses. That's all you need to uniquely identify each verse and construct entire surahs or the entire quran from them.